# Need to send ^C to CLI using GNU screen over serial interface (/dev/rfcomm0)

Tags: gnu-screen

I am connected to an embedded Linux device using GNU screen. The connection is via /dev/rfcomm0 which is a Bluetooth serial interface. I frequently forget to put an & after a CLI command, which blocks the interface until the command completes. I would like to be able to send a ctrl-C break to the CLI, but when I do the terminal just echoes ^C. I've tried changing the flow, XON/XOFF, escape sequences, :stuff $'**' with various *'s.

As far as I understand, there is no way for me to make a second screen interface into the serial device in order to send a kill.

Is there a way for me to send a ctrl-C break to the CLI over screen?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16006504/4687135) suggests you could detach from the screen session and run:

```
screen -S session_name -X at window_number stuff $'\003'
```

Alternately, could you try sending a `ctrl-z` and then using `bg` to put the process in the background?  That is, if the `ctrl-z` gets passed through correctly.

Comment: ctrl-z does not get passed through either. I'll try detaching and will report back.

Comment: detaching and using "stuff" to send that code results in ^C being echoed to the terminal, but the CLI doesn't get the break.